# Robot Framework Telnet save entire session log

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using Telnet library to operate and configure my DUT during the testing, it includes writing and reading from the terminal periodically. I'm looking how to save all the session from the beginning and till the end when the test execution is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Once you instantiate Telnet object, you can call its read_all() function to get complete log:

```
from telnetlib import Telnet
tn = Telnet('http://example.com',80)
out = tn.read_all()

with open("File.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Comment: I'm opening the connection from Robot Framework and looking for how all of it can be done in Robot Framework.